# how to get a tab bar in a Phone Gap Android application?

Tags: cordova, tabs, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Phone Gap Domain.i would like to know the procedure of implementing a tab bar in a phone gap domain.

I tried it out with the AndiDog plugin but it did not work.

please guide with exact procedure....

**EXPECTING FOR AN APT SOLUTION**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Try this....

```
<html>

<head>

<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=320; user-scalable=no” />

<meta http-equiv=”Content-type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8″>

<title>PhoneGap</title>

<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”master.css” type=”text/css” media=”screen” title=”no title” charset=”utf-8″>

<script type=”text/javascript” charset=”utf-8″ src=”phonegap.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”jquery.1.3.2.min.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript” charset=”utf-8″>

$(document).bind(“deviceready”, function() {

setupToolbars();

});

var toprated=0;

var recents=0;

var history=0;

function setupToolbars() {

window.uicontrols.createToolBar();

window.uicontrols.setToolBarTitle(“A Title”);

window.uicontrols.createTabBar();

var toprated = 0;

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem(“toprated”, “Top Rated”, “tabButton:TopRated”, {

onSelect: function() {

navigator.notification.alert(“Top Rated selected”);

window.uicontrols.updateTabBarItem(“toprated”, { badge: ++toprated });

}

 });

var recents = 0;

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem(“recents”, “Recents”, null, {

onSelect: function() {

navigator.notification.alert(“Recents selected”);

window.uicontrols.updateTabBarItem(“recents”, { badge: ++recents });

}

});

var history = 0;

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem(“history”, “History”, “icon.png”, {

onSelect: function() {

navigator.notification.alert(“History selected”);

window.uicontrols.updateTabBarItem(“history”, { badge: ++history });

}

});

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem(“search”, “Search”, “tabButton:Search”);

window.uicontrols.createTabBarItem(“downloads”, “Downloads”, “tabButton:Downloads”);

window.uicontrols.showTabBar();

window.uicontrols.showTabBarItems(“toprated”, “recents”, “history”);

}

</script>

</head>

<body id=”stage”>

<div id=”Page1″>

<br><br><br>

<h1>The tab bar is kewl!</h1>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Anurag Shukla,as usual.....i am getting the content written in the body tag....alone

Comment: I have implemented it by this method only, well i will try and code accordingly.